# R reshape dcast 0 and 1

Tags: r, casting, reshape, reshape2

Hi I have a data looks like this:

```
partNumber manufacturer supplier availability
p1         m1           s1       100
p1         m1           s2       500
p2         m2           s1       200
p2         m2           s3       300
....
```

My expected output should look like this:

```
partNumber manufacturer s1    s2    s3...
p1         m1           100   500   0 ...
p2         m2           200   0     300 ...
...
```

I was trying to implement this using dcast in reshape2 package and this is my command:

```
df.dcast <- dcast(df, partNumber + manufacturer ~ supplier, value.var="availability")
```

However, the output value is only 0 and 1, seems like it turned output to be a checkout instead of displaying the availability value.

```
partNumber manufacturer s1    s2    s3...
p1         m1           1     1     0 ...
p2         m2           1     0     1 ...
...
```

btw, while I run the command, there is a warning that

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length...
```

I don't quite understand what does the aggregation function do and any help and explanation would be apprecited.

Comment: If your partNumber and manufacturer pairs are unique then you can add  `fun.aggregate` as sum or mean and that should work. The 1s and 0s you see are the result of the aggregation function, length. The fun.aggregate argument tells dcast what function to perform upon the values found in availability with the same partNumber and manufacturer

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with the data sample you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I was thinking the same thing, however, they are supposed to be unique but looks like the 1s and 0s are caused by the 'non-unique' partNumber and manufacturer keys... What should I do in this case. Run a unique before doing the cast?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft  It is probably due to the reason that Codoremifa mentioned there exist duplicate "key pairs".. and my sample data doesn't contain it.

Comment: To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` See the link & instructions here:  http://bit.ly/SORepro   .

Comment: It may be that they are supposed to be unique (`partNumber`, `manufacturer`, and `supplier`) combinations, but they are not (if they were, an aggregation function would not come into play). You can look for an entry greater than 1 in one of the columns, or try `library("plyr"); tmp <- count(df[,1:3]); tmp[tmp$freq > 1,]` to find which combinations are duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do this with your data example I get:

```
df.dcast <- dcast(df, partNumber + manufacturer ~ supplier, value.var="availability")
df.dcast
  partNumber manufacturer  s1  s2  s3
1         p1           m1 100 500  NA
2         p2           m2 200  NA 300
```

What's most likely happening is that your `availability` column is not what you think it is. Perhaps it got converted to a factor variable because there was some text in that column in the input file. If that's the case then you need to read [R-FAQ 7.10](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f)